# Count on this LEFT OUTER query is returning 1 when I want 0

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT 
    l.id, l.name, l.store_id, COUNT(1) as reviewCount
FROM
    locations l
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    reviews r ON l.id=r.location_id
GROUP BY 
    l.id 
ORDER BY
     reviewCount DESC
```

I have 2 tables; locations, reviews. Reviews stores location_id. I want to get all locations and include the `reviewCount` for each of the locations. When there is a location that doesn't have any reviews I get a `reviewCount` of 1. But I want to get a reviewCount of 0 for those locations.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `COUNT(1) as reviewCount`? Why not `COUNT(*)`

Comment: Join the argument: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to count the matches in the second table, so count a column from that table:

```
SELECT l.id, l.name, l.store_id, COUNT(r.location_id) as reviewCount
. . .
```

What happens is that `COUNT(1)` is counting the *rows* being returned.  A row is being returned with `NULL` values from the second table.